# How to retrieve user from firestore based on property

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

In my angular app, I am using Angularfire2 and Firestore.

From the documentation I know that I can get the user with email "xyz@gmail.com" with the following command (whereby db is an instance of AngularFirestore):

```
this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"));
```

However,

```
let user = this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"));
```

does not save the user with email "xyz@gmail.com" in variable "user" but the whole collection "users".

How can I get the user with email "xyz@gmail.com"?
And how can I then get the user's attributes (e.g., the user's id)?

---

Update:

I tried the following:

[image]

The gives the error message that property "then" does not exist on type AngularFirestoreCollection.

I also tried the following:

```
let user = this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"))
.valueChanges()
.pipe(reduce((acc, curr) => curr[0], {}));
```

This also gave a syntax error.

Finally, I simply tried this:

```
let users = this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"));
let user = users[0];
console.log(user);
```

This didn't give a syntax error. However, "user" was undefined.

---

UPDATE 2:

I also tried this:

```
private async getUser() {

   let users = await this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"));

   let user = users[0];
   console.log(user);

}
```

However, "user" was still "undefined".

P.S.: A user with email "xyz@gmail.com" DOES exist in firestore.

---

UPDATE 3:

I also tried the following:

[image]

However, like with the version used in Update 1, I get an error for "reduce"
... the error message says:

```
Cannot find name "reduce"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution to my question:

```
this.userData = this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com").valueChanges();

this.userData.subscribe(users => { 

  this.user = users[0];

  console.log("this is the user:" + this.user);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let user = this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"));
```

Will not give you one user, instead it'll give you a collection of user with that email property (There can be more than one in the database)
if you know you have only one i think you can use:

```
.valueChanges()
.pipe(reduce((acc, curr) => curr[0], {}))
```

to get only the first element from the collection

Comment: Thank you for your comment ... I tried your solution. Unfortunately, it didn't work (see Update to my post)

Comment: aysnc await it's for promisses not observable.
try my solution again and subscribe if you want or use the async pipe.

    .valueChanges()
    .pipe(reduce((acc, curr) => curr[0], {}))
    .subscribe(data => this.user = data)

remember to unsubscribe in the onDestroy method!

Comment: you can also subscribe without the pipe actually if you dont use the async pipe.
this.db.collection("users", ref => ref.where('email', '==', "xyz@gmail.com"))
.valueChanges().subscribe(data => this.user = data[0]);

Comment: still gives the same error message as your first solution ... Cannot find name "reduce"

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to store new users. The recommended approach is to [call `.doc()` or `.add()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) so that the Firebase SDK auto-generates a unique id string. This is a approach scales (users/some-id-ha87sdhf87hjakshdf7323r/"displayName": "john smith" vs storing as `users/johnsmith`).

So, assuming your `users` collection is full of individual users, each with a Firestore generated uid, it's simply a matter of querying for what you want.

The nice thing about Firestore is that it support compound queries. See: [Perform simple and compound queries in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

Comment: I'm using angularfire2 so the api is slightly different from the "normal" firebase stuff you linked to ... furthermore, I already know how to query a collection (see my post) ... I just don't know how to access the result of the query

Comment: it returns a querySnapshot so you have to iterate over it with a for each loop. So, you have to `.then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
    })`

Comment: it doesn't work (see update to my post) ...please note that I'm using angularfire2 and your code is for "normal"  firebase